# Bilinear mapping property

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-groups, bilinear-operator

I was learning the topic and faced the excercise:

Let `G1`, `G2` and `G3` be finite cyclic groups of the same `order n`, and let `e(·,·) : G1 ×G2 → G3` be a pairing map. Show that, for given `g1 ∈ G1, g2 ∈ G2` and all `a,b ∈ Zn`, the following identity holds:

`e(g1^a,g2^b) = e(g1,g2)^a·b`

The proof of equality above is based on the property:
`e(g1 * g1', g2) = e(g1, g2) * e(g1', g2)`

As `e` function is a multiplication of pair members, can the property above be represented as:
`e(g1 * g1', g2) = e(g1, g2) * e(g1', g2) = (g1 * g2) * (g1' * g2)` and if so, why dont we have `g2^2` at the end ?

In other words where from the second `g2` comes from here? (`e(g1, g2) * e(g1', g2)`)

P.S. I assume that `e` is a multiplication function based on other example from learning materials I am using:
One of the most basic examples of a non-degenerate pairing involves the groups `G1, G2 and G3` all being groups of integers with addition `(Z,+)`. In this case, the following map defines a non-degenerate pairing:

`e(·,·) : Z×Z → Z (a,b) → a·b`

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: @Shaun Thank you! Sorry for unconventional formatting

Answer (score 0):

The example you give of $e: \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ can be represented as multiplication because all three groups involved are the same group.

However, in the general case, $G_1, G_2, G_3$ can all be different. So, if we have $g_1 \in G_1$ and $g_2 \in G_2$, $g_1 * g_2$ is not defined. You may write $e(g_1,g_2)$ as $g_1 * g_2$ but note that this does not correspond to any group operations of $G_1$, $G_2$ or $G_3$. This is simply a notational choice you may make. In particular, when you write $e(g_1 * g_1', g_2) = e(g_1, g_2) * e(g_1', g_2) = (g_1 \cdot g_2) * (g_1' \cdot g_2)$, you would want to distinguish the operations as I have done explicitly with different notation. The operation $*$ here is for $G_3$ and $\cdot$ is for the map $e$.

Comment: Thaks for the answer!
So in my first example, groups $G_1, G_2$ operation is not defined? I should treat it as 'some' function ?
Is there any law that helps to define mapping function, and does it depends on source groups operation?

Comment: Yes, there is no operation defined between $G_1$ and $G_2$. However, from what you've written, it seems that you are given that the map $e$ is bilinear (linear in both coordinates). So, it isn't just 'some' function, but 'some' bilinear function. As long as it is bilinear, it can be anything.